# Pin (IO) expanders

Tags: microcontroller, led

What are the effects of using pin expanders? I'm not clear on how they work exactly. I have the faint idea that the chip rapidly switches io streams, but I don't know where I picked that up. If I use pin expanders, will I see a flickering in LED lights and other outputs?
Additionally, are there any negative side effects of using pin expanders?

Comment: There were a variety of oddball port expanders. The 8255 comes to mind. There were discrete port expanders built out of 7400 parts, too. And weird ones like mos technology's 6522 that was kind of a "jack of several trades" device. I'd just recommend that you read up on the documentation for several different types of the modern incarnations of them. They probably do things in different ways, and may offer more than one kind of service, so there isn't a single answer. Which specific boards/devices have you been looking at?

Comment: A lot of this is determined on a case-by-case basis.  A lot of this is determined by reading datasheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a pin expander is a hammer, j/k. I think you mean port expander. A port expander is essentially a second IC that allows you to offload some GPIO duties from your main microcontroller. It increases the number of pins you have available. Some have special features like PWM. Your microcontroller talks to the port expander via serial or i2c or spi or other methods, telling it how to switch it's pins. Just like you would the port/pins internal to your microcontroller.

The downside is that it adds another layer of communication or code or overhead to read and write to it. They should not flicker.

The flicker may be from using a shift register, which is different method of increasing your available outputs.

Answer (score 1):

### GPIO 101

The inputs of an output port are *not* constantly driven by the CPU's internal data bus -- this would leave no room for the CPU to do anything else!  Instead, there's an internal register that latches the value to be output onto the data bus and holds onto it while the CPU goes off and does other things.  (This is often called PORTx or the likes in microcontroller datasheets, and yes, it's an actual register on the device.)

### Expanding our territory

Modern I/O expanders work in a similar way -- they simply have a serial bus interface glued to their ports instead of being wired to the CPU bus directly.  (The simplest output expander is the use of the TTL/CMOS '595 on SPI busses, and its serial interface is nothing more than a serial-in, parallel-out shift register, as you can see below (the logic diagram was taken from [TI's datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf)).  Obviously, more sophisticated expanders have a more sophisticated interface.)

[image: SN74HC595 logic diagram]

### So, you don't have to worry

The I/O expander will hang onto the output value for you, just like your microcontroller's built-in I/O ports will.  So, there's no need to worry about strobing effects, glitches, or any of that sort of trouble.

Comment: I would add a schematic of an I/O port pin, but CircuitLab doesn't have a tristate buffer :/